# Why are my Fiddle Leaf Fig's new leaves are dying?

Tags: leaves, growth, ficus

I've had four new leaves show up on my Fiddle Leaf Fig (Ficus Lyrata). However, a day after they start to unfold, the leaf dries out and turns black. What could be the reason?

I got this plant from a friend a couple of months ago and it is about 2 feet tall. The plant is kept a few feet from a west facing window, and I block the harsh afternoon light with a curtain.

[image: New leaf starting to unfold]

[image: Dead in a day]

For a little more context: 
I'm a fairly new plant parent and I love plants. I have around 20 different plants at home (yes, I went bonkers). I've been reading books to try and learn. All my other plants are thriving, and I've successfully revived a few almost dying plants - but this one mysterious problem I haven't been able to figure out.